# Do you want to have fun?

Tags: riddle, wordplay

Do you want to have some fun?
Or do you just want to make the cut?
Black or White, it's all the same.
But don't go too fast, it's just a game.
Let's just hope we're not missing anyone.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE!

Answer (score 4):

Could this be related to

> the card game **Dobble** (aka Spot It!)?

Do you want to have some fun?

> It's a game!

Or do you just want to make the cut?

> Maybe you want to win.

Black or White, it's all the same.

> The color of the images can vary, but you still need to match them.

But don't go too fast, it's just a game.

> Don't make mistakes when matching cards, it's just a game.

Let's just hope we're not missing anyone.

> the first letters of each line spell DOBBL, so perhaps the someone we're missing is "E".

Comment: That's a good try! Not what I had in mind though.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by Dan I'd say

> CHESS

Do you want to have some fun?

> It's an invitation to a game. Maybe the OP likes chess?

Or do you just want to make the cut?

> May be some phrase about taking the prize money. There are chess games with prizes indeed.

Black or White, it's all the same.

> Same chances for both sides, black and white, to win. Both colours have the same number and kinds of pieces

But don't go too fast, it's just a game.

> Take your time and think about your moves. Chess is a tactical game.

Let's just hope we're not missing anyone.

> If you do a mistage you'll probably lose a piece of your army. If you *miss* i.e. overlook an enemy's piece.

Comment: Another interesting guess. However, every part of the clue is explicitly linked to the word. So the first line wouldn't necessarily be an invitation per se.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add another answer because it's very different from the first one:

> SHAVING

Do you want to have some fun?

> Shaving can be seen as fun and, metaphorially, as a game

Or do you just want to make the cut?

> Well, this is obvious

Black or White, it's all the same.

> We usually shave all hair in a desired area and don't choose by colour

But don't go too fast, it's just a game.

> It's dangerous if you go too fast. You may end up cutting

Let's just hope we're not missing anyone.

> The aim is to erase all the hair thus we hope not to miss a single one